# Running total in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I designed an SSRS report which has a table that has a numeric column.  The table can span over multiple pages.  In the table footer I ams showing the total sum for all values of this column, and I am showing this footer on each page of the report.  However, I need this total at the end of each page to be a running total - ie it should only show the sum of all values from the beginning of the table (ie the beginning of the report) up to the footer itself.  How can this be approached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.  I added a running total column, then added a text box to the footer of the report with the expression =last(ReportItems!textbox32.Value)